# script or a java program to rename multiple files in a directory

Tags: java, linux, macos, rename, batch-rename

I have a Directory with many sub folders. There are many files in it and I need to rename the files like file_pl.properties to file_en.properties. Can you suggest a script that iterates through the folders and matches the pattern of _pl for a file and renames the file to _en

Answer (score 2):

Use this little gem from the console, it is written using Bash.

```
for FILE in `find . -name *_pl.properties`;do mv "${FILE}" "${FILE%_pl.properties}_en.properties";done
```

This code will iterate over every file in a directory and its child directories. Every time it finds a file that ends with '_pl.properties', it will then move (renames) the postfix to _en.properties.

This bash script was tested under Ubuntu and Mac OSX.

Comment: :Can this script used as shell as im on mac

Comment: @user1965834 Use the mac terminal, it defaults to running bash. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29